# Developing Software On-The-Go using a Windows Phone

Tags: windows-10, windows-8

I love being able to develop code wherever I am but sometimes I'm without my laptop and would love to have my laptop-esque setup available to me on my phone.

Since I develop for the web I have XAMPP and SASS installed on my windows pc. Could you install some kind of virtual server software on your phone and in conjunction with one-drive be able to develop websites / other software on a windows mobile?

Thanks!

Comment: Quick request for clarification: Are you trying to actually develop on the phone (that is, run an editor app, build the software if it needs it, publish it to wherever, etc.) or do you simply want to be able to use the phone for on-the-go development? If the latter, I recommend using Remote Desktop; there are at least two excellent apps for it in the store. Note that the WP8 keyboard is... *REALLY* bad for coding, though.

Comment: Yes on-the-go development. I figured a remote desktop app may be the way to go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A true laptop-esque setup is probably not possible on WP8.1 (though W10M should help there). However, if you're willing to go through Remote Desktop software, that's an option. There are two high-quality remote desktop clients for WP8 that I know of, both just called "Remote Desktop":

- The [one from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/remote-desktop/9wzdncrfj3ps) is "official" and free, and should work pretty easily with minimal effort on your part, but is less configurable.
- The [third-party client from Topperware](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/remotedesktop/9wzdncrcwnw3) (which predates the Microsoft version) has a free trial (but it's time-limited per connection), but I found it worth paying for. That one is highly configurable and tweakable, and has an excellent alternative keyboard to the built-in WP one (which is really not good for coding).

You can also try to get a Bluetooth keyboard working with the phone. That would save the screen real estate for the on-screen keyboard and would let you type a lot faster. I'm not certain if WP8.1 supports such peripherals, though (W10M does).